# How to debug a free(): invalid nex size error in Python/Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

In Kivy I get sometimes the following error:

```
*** Error in `python': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001d67800 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It doesn't happen every time I test the program, and this really puzzles me.

Searching for the error message I was led to believe that it is related to C code.
I imagine I am doing something in python that leads to this bug in kivy C code.

I'd like to know how could I track a bug like this.

Versions:

- Python version: 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
- Cython version: 0.20.1+git90-g0e6e38e-1ubuntu2
- Kivy version: 1.8.0-stable0+2014013011617^pkg23^ubuntu13.10.

Comment: what version of android are you targeting? I know android2.2 has some issues with texture id allocation that may be related ... (or is this happening in the kivy test environment? (on windows or something?) if so have you seen it on an actual device as well?)..

Comment: What platform, Kivy version, Cython version, etc? Any chance you could use a C debugger (like gdb) to get a backtrace when this happens?

Comment: I actually don't know how to use a C debugger. How is that accomplished with python/kivy? I'll edit the question to include versions.

Comment: I am getting this really early in the development. I have not yet tried it on the device. I am targeting Jelly Beam, but the problem is happening on the PC.

Comment: Install gdb and Python debug - `sudo apt-get install gdb python2.7-dbg`. Then from your app directory run `gdb --args python <script.py>`. When you get a prompt, type `r` and press Enter and your app will start. When it crashes, the Kivy window will stay open and the terminal running gdb will show a prompt. Type `bt` at this prompt and the output will be the backtrace.

Comment: @RyanP Thanks a lot! That is the answer I was looking for. Would you mind posting it as an answer so that I can choose it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, install gdb and Python debug: `sudo apt-get install gdb python2.7-dbg`

Then load your app in gdb: `gdb --args python <script.py>`

You should receive a gdb prompt `(gdb)`. Type `r` and press Enter. Your program will start running like normal (albeit slower).

Once your app crashes, the Kivy window will remain open and the gdb shell will show a prompt again. Type `bt` at this prompt to see the backtrace.

Example:

```
$ gdb --args python segtest.py
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python2.7...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python2.7...done.
done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/python segtest.py
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/ryan/.kivy/logs/kivy_14-07-28_13.txt
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 169 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60s
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pygame, img_pil, img_gif 
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60s
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600s
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <textinput.label> with limit=None, timeout=60.0s
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <textinput.width> with limit=None, timeout=60.0s
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.8.1-dev
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Display driver x11
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Actual window size: 800x600
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Actual color bits r8 g8 b8 a8
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Actual depth bits: 24
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Actual stencil bits: 8
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Actual multisampling samples: 4
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <3.0 Mesa 10.1.3>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel Open Source Technology Center>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile >
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <1.30>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Fragment compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Vertex compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] [ImagePygame ] Load </home/ryan/git/aeris2/kivy/kivy/data/glsl/default.png>
[DEBUG  ] [Modules     ] Start <inspector> with config {}
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] Loading kv <./test.kv>

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff5971db6 in __pyx_f_4kivy_8graphics_12instructions_6Canvas_add (__pyx_v_self=0x7fffe2ec4a68, 
    __pyx_v_c=0x920190 <_Py_NoneStruct>, __pyx_skip_dispatch=<optimized out>) at kivy/graphics/instructions.c:8532
8532        ((struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4kivy_8graphics_12instructions_Instruction *)__pyx_v_c->__pyx_vtab)->radd(__pyx_v_c, ((struct __pyx_obj_4kivy_8graphics_12instructions_InstructionGroup *)__pyx_v_self));
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff5971db6 in __pyx_f_4kivy_8graphics_12instructions_6Canvas_add (__pyx_v_self=0x7fffe2ec4a68, 
    __pyx_v_c=0x920190 <_Py_NoneStruct>, __pyx_skip_dispatch=<optimized out>) at kivy/graphics/instructions.c:8532
#1  0x00007ffff597487e in __pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_12instructions_6Canvas_6add (
    __pyx_v_c=0x920190 <_Py_NoneStruct>, __pyx_v_self=0x7fffe2ec4a68) at kivy/graphics/instructions.c:8611
#2  __pyx_pw_4kivy_8graphics_12instructions_6Canvas_7add (
    __pyx_v_self=<kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas at remote 0x7fffe2ec4a68>, __pyx_v_c=None)
    at kivy/graphics/instructions.c:8591
#3  0x000000000052ccbc in call_function (oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=0x7fffffffd870) at ../Python/ceval.c:4008
#4  PyEval_EvalFrameEx (
    f=f@entry=Frame 0x7fffdfa10050, for file /home/ryan/git/aeris2/kivy/kivy/core/window/__init__.py, line 647, in add_widget (self=<WindowPygame(_context=<Context(sandbox=None) at remote 0x7ffff659a740>, single_vkeyboard=True, _keyboards={'system': <Keyboard(widget=None, callback=None, window=<...>, target=None) at remote 0x7fffe2ebf0b8>}, _vkeyboard_cls=None, _system_keyboard=<...>, _pos=(0, 0), allow_vkeyboard=False, use_syskeyboard=True, flags=1073741843, trigger_keyboard_height=<ClockEvent(_last_dt=0, cid=207, clock=<ClockBase at remote 0x7ffff65c4a28>, weak_callback=<WeakMethod(_func=<function at remote 0x7fffe2e9fed8>, _obj=<weakref at remote 0x7fffe2ec2050>, _class=<type at remote 0x1029ac0>) at remote 0x7fffe2ebc9d0>, callback=None, timeout=<float at remote 0xf0ea98>, _is_triggered=False, _dt=<float at remote 0xa83608>, loop=False) at remote 0x7fffe2ebc990>, initialized=True, docked_vkeyboard=False, dpi=<float at remote 0xf0e930>, trigger_create_window=<ClockEvent(_last_dt=0, cid=207, clock=<...>, weak_callback=<W...(truncated), throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:2666
...
...
...
```